# Pythonic type hints with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting

Let's take a simple function that takes a str and returns a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
def csv_to_df(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1, sep='\t', comment='#')
```

***What is the recommended pythonic way of adding type hints to this function?***

If I ask python for the type of a DataFrame it returns `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.
The following won't work though, as it'll tell me that pandas is not defined.

```
 def csv_to_df(path: str) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame:
     return pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1, sep='\t', comment='#')
```

Comment: But you're using the `pd` alias, and you can probably define custom types.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye if I try pd.core.frame.DataFrame I'll get an `AttributeError` instead of a `NameError`.

Comment: I am not an authority on "pythonicity" but I would recommend doc-strings (using `''' this function takes a inputType and returns an outputType '''`) this is also what will be shown if someone calls `help(yourFunction)` function on your function.

Comment: the library `dataenforce` allows to check for data types inside the data frame https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce

Comment: Related on r/learnpython: [How to specify pandas type-hint with columns](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/103xp7l/how_to_specify_pandas_typehint_with_columns/)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Why not just use `pd.DataFrame`?

```
import pandas as pd
def csv_to_df(path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1, sep='\t', comment='#')
```

Result is the same:

```
> help(csv_to_df)
Help on function csv_to_df in module __main__:
csv_to_df(path:str) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: it also won't allow specifying dtypes for specific columns, which could be extremely useful

Comment: @Philipp_Kats Currently there is no way to specify dtypes for DataFrame columns in type hints, and [I haven't seen](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25601) any work done in this direction (correct me if I'm wrong). Linking a related question on type hints with NumPy and dtypes: [*Type hint for NumPy ndarray dtype?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54503964). You will see that it's also [not implemented there yet](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs/issues/7).

Comment: This gives an error in mypy `error: No library stub file for module 'pandas'`

Comment: @user2304916 See [Unable to suppress `No library stub file for module...` error](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3905).

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` doesn't tell much unfortunately. The underlying df could have literally any shape and you wouldn't know.

Comment: Learning about the shape and column names / types of a dataframe is different than knowing that the type of the object is a dataframe. 

Consider the difference between making sure a variable is an int, and making sure that int is greater than 3. Its the same distinction.

Comment: @Nesha25 It is also similar to the difference between a `list[int]` and `list[str]`. Without the type parameter telling you what's "inside" the list, you don't really know what you can legally do with the contents. The same applies to dataframes. Additionally, your example of an "int greater than 3" is unusual indeed, but such "value constraints" are not so unusual in type systems - consider for example a "a non-null pointer", "non-zero divisor" or "object with validated email address". Such types are used in many places.

Comment: While not Pandas, StaticFrame (of which I am an author) permits type-hinting DataFrames with specific dtypes per column (as well as types for the index and columns labels): [see this overview](https://towardsdatascience.com/type-hinting-dataframes-for-static-analysis-and-runtime-validation-3dedd2df481d)

Answer (score 29):

I'm currently doing the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar
PandasDataFrame = TypeVar('pandas.core.frame.DataFrame')
def csv_to_df(path: str) -> PandasDataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1, sep='\t', comment='#')
```

Which gives:

```
> help(csv_to_df)
Help on function csv_to_df in module __main__:

csv_to_df(path:str) -> ~pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Don't know how pythonic that is, but it's understandable enough as a type hint, I find.

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov would you mind elaborating on your comment? Sometimes I'm not sure what is and isn't 'pythonic'.

Comment: I see people downvoting this answer. For context, this was the solution I found for my own question, and for all intents and purposes it works just fine. The more pythonic solution above, which I accepted as correct answer (but does have its own perks, see comments), was only provided 8 months afterwards.

Comment: It's not pythonic since it is less clear and harder to maintain than the accepted answer for this question. Since the type path here is not verified by the compiler it won't raise errors if it's wrong. This could happen from a typo in your `TypeVar` arg or change to the module itself.

Comment: I receive a warning when I use this: `The argument to 'TypeVar()' must be a string equal to the variable name to which it is assigned `

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov These "pythonic" and "not pythonic" arguments are like a mantra for many "Pythonists". I think we should stop arguments in this style. A had never heard this type of argumentation from e.g. Java developer. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with this solution.

Comment: This is not the correct use of a type variable. A `TypeVar` exists to link two types together ([mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html)). You probably meant a type _alias_: `PandasDataFrame = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Answer (score 22):

**Update Nov 2023**

Since the maintainer of `dataenforce` discontinued its development, I thought I'd update this answer. [According to him](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce/issues/15#issuecomment-1517344091):

> Alternatively, I recommend using [pandera](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera) which provides a similar functionality (& much more!)

---

**Original answer**

Now there is a pip package that can help with this.
https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce

You can install it with `pip install dataenforce` and use very pythonic type hints like:

```py
def preprocess(dataset: Dataset["id", "name", "location"]) -> Dataset["location", "count"]:
    pass
```

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [pandera](https://github.com/pandera-dev/pandera).

> pandera provides a flexible and expressive API for performing data validation on dataframe-like objects to make data processing pipelines more readable and robust.
> Dataframes contain information that pandera explicitly validates at runtime. This is useful in production-critical or reproducible research settings.

---

The advantage of pandera is that you can also specify dtypes of individual DataFrame columns. The following example uses pandera to run-time enforce a DataFrame containing a single column of integers:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera
from pandera.typing import DataFrame, Series

class Integers(pandera.SchemaModel):
    number: Series[int] 

@pandera.check_types
def my_fn(a: DataFrame[Integers]) -> None:
    pass

# This works
df = pd.DataFrame({"number": [ 2002, 2003]})
my_fn(df)

# Raises an exception
df = pd.DataFrame({"number": [ 2002.0, 2003]})
my_fn(df)

# Raises an exception
df = pd.DataFrame({"number": [ '2002', 2003]})
my_fn(df)
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446142/8419574) which explains the usage of the package `data-science-types`.

```
pip install data-science-types
```

Demo

```
# program.py

import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]}) # OK
df1: pd.DataFrame = pd.Series([1,2,3]) # error: Incompatible types in assignment
```

Run using mypy the same way:

`$ mypy program.py`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is buried at bottom. **In 2021 this is the best answer.**

Note too the comment by Daniel Malachov following the linked answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446142/8419574).

Comment: @user3897315 - I disagree that this is the best answer in 2021. If you visit [data-science-types on GitHub](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types) you'll find the repository has been archived, and the README updated (on Feb 16 2021) with the following note:

"⚠️  **this project has mostly stopped development** ⚠️
The pandas team and the numpy team are both in the process of integrating type stubs into their codebases, and we don't see the point of competing with them."

Comment: I agree, but following that I don't see a timeline when pandas or numpy will have these pushed or ETA in their roadmap.

Answer (score 1):

This is straying from the original question but building off of @dangom's answer using `TypeVar` and @Georgy's comment that there is no way to specify datatypes for DataFrame columns in type hints, you could use a simple work-around like this to specify datatypes in a DataFrame:

```
from typing import TypeVar
DataFrameStr = TypeVar("pandas.core.frame.DataFrame(str)")
def csv_to_df(path: str) -> DataFrameStr:
    return pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1, sep='\t', comment='#')
```