# Type hint for NumPy ndarray dtype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like a function to include a type hint for NumPy `ndarray`'s alongside with its `dtype`.

With lists, for example, one could do the following...

```
def foo(bar: List[int]):
   ...
```

...in order to give a type hint that `bar` has to be `list` consisting of `int`'s.

Unfortunately, this syntax throws exceptions for NumPy `ndarray`:

```
def foo(bar: np.ndarray[np.bool]):
   ...

> np.ndarray[np.bool]) (...) TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Is it possible to give `dtype`-specific type hints for `np.ndarray`?

Comment: Last time I answered a type-hinting question I couldn't find much numpy specific information

Comment: What is `List`.  `list` with lowercase is a normal Python function/type.

Comment: Give a fuller context - what `typing` are you importing?  How are you using typing?  What `numpy` specific typing have you found and imported?

Comment: @hpaulj, `List` is a built in mypy type: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtin_types.html#built-in-types

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out [data-science-types](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types) package.

```
pip install data-science-types
```

MyPy now has access to Numpy, Pandas, and Matplotlib stubs.
Allows scenarios like:

```
# program.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1: np.ndarray[np.int64] = np.array([3, 7, 39, -3])  # OK
arr2: np.ndarray[np.int32] = np.array([3, 7, 39, -3])  # Type error

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]}) # OK
df1: pd.DataFrame = pd.Series([1,2,3]) # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Series[int]", variable has type "DataFrame")
```

Use mypy like normal.

```
$ mypy program.py
```

Usage with function-parameters

```
def f(df: pd.DataFrame):
    return df.head()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
    print(f(x))

$ mypy program.py
> Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for asking, I tested to make sure. Will extend answer with example.

Comment: When executing scripts that use this library, I still get the TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.

So, PyCharm doesn't give a type warning anymore, but there is an error when executed.

Comment: Are you getting this for the pd.DataFrame or for Numpy? I have gotten this before but I forget how I reproduced it. I'm also not in PyCharm, this was just using the terminal of JupyterLab to run the `.py` file.

Comment: I've installed `mypy` and `data-science-types` and when I try the example I'm getting `error: "ndarray" expects no type arguments, but 1 given`.  Any solution? I found sth about installing `mypy` from repo but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's more, `data-science-types` messing with `np.lingalg.norm`: `error: Module has no attribute "norm"`.

Comment: From data-science-types github:
⚠️ this project has mostly stopped development ⚠️

The pandas team and the numpy team are both in the process of integrating type stubs into their codebases, and we don't see the point of competing with them.

Answer (score 49):

You could check out [nptyping](https://pypi.org/project/nptyping/):

```py
from nptyping import NDArray, Bool

def foo(bar: NDArray[Bool]):
   ...
```

Or you could just use strings for type hints:

```py
def foo(bar: 'np.ndarray[np.bool]'):
   ...
```

Comment: What does using stringy type hints do? Just show up as documentation? Or can editors actually parse them and enforce them?

Comment: It serves as documentation and doesn't really do much (unless you start parsing them using inspection for some reason). Some editors (e.g. PyCharm) are smart enough though to see if they can make sense of textual type hints.

Sometimes you'll have no other choice than to use textual type hints. For example when hinting a method's parameter to be of the same type of the class that holds the method.

Comment: Note that this is now accessible at `numpy.typing.NDArray` as of 1.20, not an external package: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html

Comment: @RH you can add `from __future__ import annotations` to properly type-hint a method that accepts a parameter with the same type as the class it's defined in.

Answer (score 14):

To the best of my knowledge it's not possible yet to specify `dtype` in numpy array type hints in function signatures. It is planned to be implemented at some point in the future. See [numpy GitHub issue #7370](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370) and [numpy-stubs GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs) for more details on the current development status.

Answer (score 10):

One informal solution for type documentation is the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Tuple, Union, Optional
import numpy as np

Shape = TypeVar("Shape")
DType = TypeVar("DType")


class Array(np.ndarray, Generic[Shape, DType]):
    """
    Use this to type-annotate numpy arrays, e.g.

        def transform_image(image: Array['H,W,3', np.uint8], ...):
            ...

    """
    pass


def func(arr: Array['N,2', int]):
    return arr*2


print(func(arr = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)])))
```

We've been using this at my company and made a MyPy checker that actually checks that the shapes work out (which we should release at some point).

Only thing is it doesn't make PyCharm happy (ie you still get the nasty warning lines):

[image]

Comment: I am very happy to hear that!!! Please release the checker as soon as you can!:) Or a stub file or something.