# How to define NamedTuple class containing a NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-typing

I am trying to define a a class of namedtuples that contains an array, but with no success.

I have tried using `np.zeros(shape=(16))` or `np.empty(2, dtype = int8)`
but with no success.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import numpy as np

class BasicDemodStatsMsg(NamedTuple):

    header: IcdHeader

    field1: np.uint32

    field2: np.uint32

    field3: np.uint16

    reserved: np.zeros(shape=(16))

    checksum: np.uint16
```

At the end I would like to have a class that has a fixed size of bytes in the memory and can be packed and unpacked to and from byte arrays.

Comment: Have you successfully defined such a class that does *not* contain an array?

Comment: yes, without the array it works perfectly

Comment: Could you show how you did that?

Comment: the same code but without the reserved field

Comment: And what is `NamedTuple`? Where does it come from?

Comment: nametuple is a type of collection in python

Comment: It's `collections.namedtuple` not `collections.NamedTuple` @Yarom.

Comment: As @Ben said `collections.namedtuple` is a thing. The only `NamedTuple` I can think of right now is `typing.NamedTuple` and that is only for typing purpose.

Comment: it's typing.NamedTuple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type hint for NumPy ndarray dtype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503964/type-hint-for-numpy-ndarray-dtype)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is related to the data type;  [`np.zeros()` is a method which returns `np.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), the actual data type. This is fine:

```
>>> class BasicDemodStatsMsg(typing.NamedTuple):
...     field1: np.uint32
...     field2: np.uint32
...     field3: np.uint16
...     checksum: np.uint16
...     reserved: np.ndarray = np.zeros(shape=16)
...
>>>
```

You should be extremely wary about how `reserved` is used, as it's a mutable default argument. It may be more appropriate to use a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and a therefore allow yourself to use [the default factory to create it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import NamedTuple

@dataclass
class BasicDemodStatsMsg(NamedTuple):
    field1: np.uint32
    field2: np.uint32
    field3: np.uint16
    checksum: np.uint16
    reserved: np.ndarray = field(default_factory=lambda: np.zeros(shape=16, dtype=np.uint8))
```

Note that the default attribute is the last one declared; this is because non-default fields can't follow defaults in named tuples.

Comment: i need to specify the type of the array, for example uint8, which does not happen in your solution.

Comment: You can just specify the type normally @Yarom: `reserved: np.ndarray = field(default_factory=lambda: np.zeros(shape=16, dtype=np.uint8))` I've also updated the answer to demonstrate this.