# Adding generic typing to function signature with pandas Series results in 'type' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, pandas, mypy, python-typing

`Mypy` is correctly telling me that the following is missing the generic arg for `pd.Series`

```py
def foo(x : pd.Series) -> None:
     pass
```

When I add the arg like so

```py
from typing import Any

def foo(x : pd.Series[Any]) -> None:
     pass
```

and I try to run my code using `Python 3.10.10` and using `python myfile.py` to run it I get the following

```
def foo(x: pd.Series[Any]) -> None:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm also using `pandas-stubs==1.5.3.230203` for `pandas` type stubs.

[Related question here indicates this type hinting should be possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503964/type-hint-for-numpy-ndarray-dtype) [I've also found code examples here](https://cs.github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/ed4a08a98cc1313d1ab4646ef5828060bbb35c34/src/bokeh/plotting/_plot.py#L75)

Comment: What python version are you using, typing API has been evolving very quickly ? Also please [edit] to add the full traceback leading to the `TypeError`.

Comment: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` indicates that at runtime, `pandas.Series` is not a generic class, but it's modelled as a generic class in the stubs. You can fix this by adding `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your module.

Comment: The linked dupe mentions `annotations` future import in one of answers about `pd.Series`, which is exactly your case. Also you can use string annotations directly (`def foo(x: 'pd.Series[Any]') -> None: ...`)

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` solved it. I initially didn't try it because it was for Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 and I'm on Python 3.10. Should've tried sooner thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`from __future__ import annotations` seemed to solve it.

Comment: This will not work in all cases, e.g. `S = TypeVar('S', bound=pd.Series[Any])` will still fail.

Comment: The problem is that Series is defined as a Generic type in pandas-stubs, but not in the actual pandas library.


It's helpful in many cases, but can cause problems in some places, like you are seeing here.


If it is something that only mypy can see, like type hints with `from future import __annotations__` or gated behind a `if TYPE_CHECKING`, then you should (and depending on your strictness settings, might have to) parameterize it