# How do I specify the return type of a PySpark function as a dataframe?

Tags: python, function, dataframe, pyspark

I was working on some coding challenges recently that involved passing a Spark dataframe into a Python function and returning a new dataframe.  The syntax I remember was something like:

```
def sampleFunction(df: Dataframe) -> Dataframe:
    * do stuff *
    return newDF
```

I'm trying to create my own examples now, but I'm unable to specify dataframe as an input/output type.  I assume there's something I need to import to make dataframe an acceptable type, but I have Googled this nonstop for the past hour, and I can't find a single example of how to make this work in PySpark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic type hints with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890844/pythonic-type-hints-with-pandas)

Comment: I don't believe so.  I'm working with Spark dataframes, not Pandas.

Comment: @EricJ please mark my reply as final answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import `DataFrame` type in your code and also use data type name as `DataFrame` not **Dataframe** as you mentioned in code

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
>>> def sampleFunction(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
...     df1 = df.withColumn("necol", lit(1))
...     return df1
... 
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions  import *
>>> df.show()
+---------+----------+----------+
|DEVICE_ID|  MIN_DATE|  MAX_DATE|
+---------+----------+----------+
|        1|2019-08-29|2019-08-31|
|        2|2019-08-27|2019-09-02|
+---------+----------+----------+

>>> newdf = sampleFunction(df)
>>> newdf.show()
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|DEVICE_ID|  MIN_DATE|  MAX_DATE|necol|
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|        1|2019-08-29|2019-08-31|    1|
|        2|2019-08-27|2019-09-02|    1|
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was hiding in there somewhere, but I couldn't find it.