# How to use kfp Artifact with sklearn?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I'm trying to develop a custom pipeline with kubeflow pipeline (kfp) components inside Vertex AI (Google Cloud Platform). The steps of the pipeline are:

1. read data from a big query table
2. create a pandas `DataFrame`
3. use the `DataFrame` to train a K-Means model
4. deploy the model to an endpoint

Here there is the code of the step 2. I had to use `Output[Artifact]` as output because `pd.DataFrame` type that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890844/pythonic-type-hints-with-pandas) did not work.

```py
@component(base_image="python:3.9", packages_to_install=["google-cloud-bigquery","pandas","pyarrow"])
def create_dataframe(
    project: str,
    region: str,
    destination_dataset: str,
    destination_table_name: str,
    df: Output[Artifact],
):
    
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project, location=region)
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, destination_dataset)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(destination_table_name)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)

    df = client.list_rows(table).to_dataframe()
```

Here the code of the step 3:

```py
@component(base_image="python:3.9", packages_to_install=['sklearn'])
def kmeans_training(
        dataset: Input[Artifact],
        model: Output[Model],
        num_clusters: int,
):
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    model = KMeans(num_clusters, random_state=220417)
    model.fit(dataset)
```

The run of the pipeline is stopped due to the following error:

```py
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Artifact'
```

Is it possible to convert Artifact to `numpy array` or `Dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the following codes. Now I'm able to train the model in the step 3 with the output from the step 2.

Step 2:

```py
@component(base_image="python:3.9", packages_to_install=["google-cloud-bigquery","pandas","pyarrow"])
def create_dataframe(
    project: str,
    region: str,
    destination_dataset: str,
    destination_table_name: str,
    df: Output[Dataset],
):
    
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project, location=region)
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, destination_dataset)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(destination_table_name)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)

    train = client.list_rows(table).to_dataframe()
    
    train.to_csv(df.path)
```

Step 3:

```py
@component(base_image="python:3.9", packages_to_install=['sklearn','pandas','joblib'])
def kmeans_training(
        dataset: Input[Dataset],
        model_artifact: Output[Model],
        num_clusters: int,
):
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import pandas as pd
    from joblib import dump
    
    data = pd.read_csv(dataset.path)
    
    model = KMeans(num_clusters, random_state=220417)
    model.fit(data)
    
    dump(model, model_artifact.path)
```