# Type hinting dataframe with specific columns or indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-hinting

Is it possible to define a new type (or alias) which refers to a pandas DataFrame with specific columns or indices?

For example, in the same code I often use a DataFrame with columns *x* and *z*. Also as slices of it, Series with the indices *x* and *z*. Let's say I want to call these Curve and Point.

Is there a method similar to this, in order to be more specific than just hinting to a general DataFrame?

```py
import pandas as pd

Curve = type(pd.Dataframe(columns=['x','z']))
Point = type(pd.Series(index=['x', 'z']))

def function(a: Curve) -> Point:
    return a.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265617/11246056